# MySQL query inside ssh, inside bash, with arguments

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I'm writing a small bash script to get a random sample of a database table, connecting through ssh.

```
ssh $SERVER 'mysql -e "SELECT * FROM ${TABLE} WHERE RAND() < ${PROBABILITY} LIMIT ${LIMIT}" -uroot -p ${DATABASE} > temp_dump_file.sql'
```

I can't get the arguments to be interpreted. The error is:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE RAND() <  LIMIT' at line 1
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @l0b0, the reason it's failing is because you're using single quotes, so `${TABLE}` etc won't be expanded properly. Try swapping your use of quotes:

```
ssh $SERVER "mysql -e 'SELECT * FROM ${TABLE} WHERE RAND() < ${PROBABILITY} LIMIT ${LIMIT}' -uroot -p ${DATABASE} > temp_dump_file.sql"
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash won't expand variables inside single [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).